# node.js - "libxmljs" module error

Tags: node.js, libxml-js

```
node -v
v4.4.7
npm -v
v2.15.8
node-gyp -v
v3.4.0
```

I'm trying to run my node app which uses `libxmljs` module and i'm getting this wierd error:

```
libxmljs/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: /link/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V837AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemoryEl
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at bindings (/link/node_modules/libxmljs/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/link/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/bindings.js:1:99)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I tried to `npm update` and installing `libxmljs` again. Doesn't work.
Any tips?

Comment: Did you install that module with a different Node version than that you're using now?

Comment: @robertklep
No, but i DID upgrade node lately.
Is it possible that there are two versions of node installed and that this module reference the older one ?
If so, how can I complete remove the older ?

Comment: I don't think that that can happen. Did you try and reinstall the module (remove it from `node_modules` first, just to be sure) with your current Node version?

Comment: @robertklep did it now. Now i'm getting this error: "Error: Could not locate the bindings file."
I've rebuild it with node-gyp, and now I'm getting the error in the question again :(

Comment: Why not just use `npm i libxmljs`?

Comment: @robertklep what does the "i" mean ?

Comment: Short for `install`

Comment: @robertklep I don't understand. I did it.

Comment: You initially said in your comment that you ran `sudo node-gyp rebuild`, which shouldn't be necessary if you re-install the package. I just installed the package myself (same Node version), that worked fine for me.

Comment: @robertklep ok.. but it's kind of the same.. I'm still stuck with that issue.
It's important to mention that I'm installing that module inside another module I build.
The app i'm running uses that module I'm building, but I didn't install libxmljs for it (only install it for the module I'm building)

Comment: @robertklep can you try to install it in a module within your app ?

Comment: Tried that, worked just fine. I assume that your module has `libxmljs` declared as a (regular) dependency?

Comment: @robertklep what do you mean regular dependency? I've just npm install it, and require it inside my code

Comment: Declared in the `dependencies` object of the `package.json` that belongs to your module.

Comment: @robertklep yes. I'm always using --save

Comment: If you changed node version on your system, then binary libraries can not to bind correctly with it. This is a common issue but easy to solve: If you always install your modules with `npm install --save`, just need to remove (or rename) node_modules directory and then execute `npm install` to rebuild it.
If you installed any modules without the '--save' option, then you should reinstall it by hand (better with '--save' this time).

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @MuneemHabib Yes. The problem is that i've installed node via apt-get. The environment wasn't updated with the latest version/